# How to integrate ngrams function with freq_terms in qdap package?

Tags: r, n-gram, qdap

I like the qdap freq_terms functions. It's very straightforward and does exactly what I need, at least most of the time. However, there are occasions where the freq_terms function isn't sufficient enough. For a text analysis I need instead of a term frequency data frame a bigrams frequency data frame. I was wondering if it is possible somehow to integrate the ngrams function with the freq_terms function. I haven't figured out how yet.

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you very much in advance!

Ideally it would have worked like this:

```
freq_terms(text.var, top = 20, at.least = 1, stopwords = NULL,
extend = TRUE, ngrams = 2, ...)
```

I know I doesn't work like that, but is there another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: `@Tyler Rinker` is this easy to do to your opinion?